# Regular expression for Dutch zip / postal code

Tags: javascript, regex, zipcode

I'm trying to build a regular expression in javascript to validate a Dutch zipcode.

The zipcode should contain 4 numbers, then optionally a space and then 2 (case insensitive) letters

Valid values:

```
1001aa  
1001Aa  
1001 AA
```

I now have this, but it does not work:

```
var rege = /^([0-9]{4}[ ]+[a-zA-Z]{2})$/;
```

Comment: You are using breakets arround the space, you use those to define a range of characters e.g. `[0-6]` does 0 till 6. Just replace it with ` ?` (a space and a questionmark to make it optional

Comment: As an aside: Dutch postal codes never start with a zero.

Comment: Nor are there postcodes ending in SS, SA or SD.

Comment: Thanks Arjan / Bart: how would you define those extra rules in var rege = /^([0-9]{4} ?[a-zA-Z]{2})$/;

Comment: @Florian - I added a final test to my answer below that will eliminate SS, SA, and SD.  Try that one out! :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Edited to handle no leading 0 requirement for Dutch postal codes, and to eliminate matches for SS, SA, and SD.  This should do it all for you.

Final regex:

```
var rege = /^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i;
```

Fiddle unit test: http://jsfiddle.net/hgU3u/

Here's a breakdown:

1. `^` matches beginning of string
2. `[1-9][0-9]{3}` matches a single non-zero digit, and three 0-9 digits
3. `?` matches 0 or 1 spaces (you could use `*` to match 0 or more spaces)
4. `(?!sa|sd|ss)` is a lookahead test to check that the remainder is not "sa", "sd", or "ss".
5. `[a-z]{2}` matches 2 a-z characters
6. `$` matches the end of the string
7. `i` at the end is the case-insensitive modifier

Comment: Yes, this is also a correct solution. A + in regex is one or more "hits" of the previous one character regex (or a pattern in parentheses).

Comment: Thanks for the help here - used and upvoted

Answer (score 9):

In case you have trouble using this as pattern for bootstrap validation I suggest you change it to:

```
    ^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss|SA|SD|SS)[A-Za-z]{2}$
```

This way it is still case-insensitive and accepted by the bootstrap validator.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution. The i in the end makes it case-insensitive:

```
var rege = /^\d{4} ?[a-z]{2}$/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

The excluded combinations, `SA SD SS`, need to be typed right after the ! sign to deliver a valid outcome; so, not `! SA|SD|SS` but `!SA|SD|SS` and they introduced the :space: code.

My Dutch NL postcode regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3}[[:space:]]{0,1}(?!SA|SD|SS)[A-Z]{2}$ or
^[1-9][0-9]{3}[ ]{0,1}(?!SA|SD|SS)[A-Z]{2}$ works also (depends on software version on your server, the [:space:] code is not always accepted)
```

1. ^ asserts position at start of a line
2. Match a single character present in the list below [1-9]
   1-9 matches a single character in the range between 1 (index 49) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
3. Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]
   {3} matches the previous token exactly 3 times
   0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
4. Match a single character present in the list below [[:space:]]
   {0,1} matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [:space:] matches a whitespace character, including a line break [ \t\r\n\v\f] (also written as \s)
5. Negative Lookahead (?!SA|SD|SS)
   Assert that the Regex below does not match
   1st Alternative SA
   SA matches the characters SA literally (case sensitive)
   2nd Alternative SD
   SD matches the characters SD literally (case sensitive)
   3rd Alternative SS
   SS matches the characters SS literally (case sensitive)
6. Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
   {2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times
   A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
7. $ asserts position at the end of a line

The JavaScript function I made with it:

```
function checkpostcode(){
$("#result_postcode").text("");
var xpr="^[1-9][0-9]{3}[[:space:]]{0,1}(?!SA|SD|SS)[A-Z]{2}$";
var pcRegex = new RegExp(xpr,"g");
var pccheck = document.getElementById("id_postcode");
if(pcRegex.test(pccheck.value)){
$("#result_postcode").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class=\"fa fa-check text-success\"></i>");
$("#result_postcode").css("color", "green");
$("#id_postcode").css("border", "2px solid green");
$("#id_postcode").css("background-color", "#bdf5bd");
    validator();
} else {
$("#result_postcode").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class=\"fa fa-remove text-danger\"></i>");
$("#result_postcode").css("color", "red");
$("#id_postcode").css("border", "1px solid red");   
}}
```

This is called from a form input field in PHP:

```
echo"<input type=\"text\" id=\"id_postcode\" name=\"postcode\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"4 cijfers spatie 2 letters\" style=\"width:50%\" oninput=\"checkpostcode();\" required>";
echo"<span id=\"result_postcode\"></span>";
```

`validator()` is a JavaScript function that runs every time an input field has changed and when the page finishes loading for the first time. It finally executes the display of the input button by providing the right CSS to display that button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
validator();
});
</script>
```

To show the disabled button:

```
function validator(){
var postc=document.getElementById("id_postcode");
var h=postc.value.length;
if(h>0){
//als aan alle eisen voldaan wordt button vrijgeven
$("#maak_account_id").prop("disabled", false); //activeer de button
$("#maak_account_id").removeClass(); //opmaak wissen
$("#maak_account_id").addClass("button enabled"); //opmaak plaatsen
}else{
$("#maak_account_id").prop("disabled", true); //activeer een button
$("#maak_account_id").removeClass(); //opmaak wissen
$("#maak_account_id").addClass("button disabled"); //opmaak plaatsen

}
```

And the form button:

```
<input name="maak_account" id="maak_account_id" type="submit" value="Maak mijn account aan" style="float: right;" disabled>
```

Comment: Only checking for proper input at the front-end still makes the form vulnerable to wrong inputting if you have the proper tools (like an F12 button). Always also validate at the back-end side.

Answer (score 0):

I use this when i need to catch both uppercase and lowercase zipcodes:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss|SA|SD|SS)([A-Z]{2}$|[a-z]{2}$)
```

This catches zipcodes like:

- 1111aa
- 1111AA
- 1111 aa
- 1111 AA

and prevents answers like:

- 111aa
- 1111Aa
- 1111 aA
- etc...

I hope this helps for people who need to catch both upper and lowercase.