# Dutch postal codes regex R

Tags: r, regex

I have vectors `from` and `to`:

`from <- c("Valid from", "Zipcode from", "0000AA", "1798AA", "8900AA", "9167aa")`

`to <- c("Valid from", "Zipcode to", "1797zz", "8899ZZ", "9166ZZ", "9999ZZ")`

I want to write a `str_detect` regex that only gives `TRUE` when there is a Dutch postal code (i.e., four digits first and two letters after. Non case sensitive).

I also found this question before: [Regular expression for Dutch zip / postal code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898523/regular-expression-for-dutch-zip-postal-code). But this regex does not seem to work for me.

My attempts all give `FALSE` for all entries of `to` and `from`:

`str_detect(test, "/^[1-9][0-9]{4} [a-z]{2}$/i")`

`str_detect(test, "^/d{4}?/w{2}$")`

And more attempts failed. Thank you in advance. Probably missing something fairly obvious :)

Comment: `/d` must be `\\d`. `/` at the start and end should not be used. Try `str_detect(from, "^\\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$")`, see this [R demo](https://ideone.com/Ou6uET).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match digits with `\d` pattern, and use double backslashes in the string literals, `"\\d"`. Also, you cannot use regex delimiters, `/` at the start and end, you need to just pass the pattern.

To make the pattern case insensitive, you may use `(?i)` at the start of the pattern, or, here, just use `[A-Za-z]` to match any ASCII letter.

You can use

```
str_detect(from, "^\\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PanB5n/1) and an [R demo](https://ideone.com/Ou6uET):

```
library(stringr)
from <- c("Valid from", "Zipcode from", "0000AA", "1798AA", "8900AA", "9167aa")
to <- c("Valid from", "Zipcode to", "1797zz", "8899ZZ", "9166ZZ", "9999ZZ")
str_detect(from, "^\\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$")
# => [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
from[str_detect(from, "^\\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$")]
# => [1] "0000AA" "1798AA" "8900AA" "9167aa"
 
str_detect(to, "^\\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$")
to[str_detect(to, "^\\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$")]
# => [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# => [1] "1797zz" "8899ZZ" "9166ZZ" "9999ZZ"
```